# For what - conversion_user table in magento database

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to know for what it's conversion_user table in magento 1.9 database? I got that table in MySQL and it's got 3 milions records and 500MB size.. Can i empty it?

Answer (score 0):

**There is no conversion_user table in a default Magento 1.9 installation.**

That table belongs to a custom extension that you have installed on your Magento.

To find out what extension run this `find` command via `ssh` inside magento root:

```
find app lib -type f -exec grep -iHn --color=always 'conversion_table' {} \;
```

Once you know what the extension is you can decide either to keep it or delete it.

Once you delete it you can safely empty that table.

**Disclaimer:** always backup DB and files before you make any changes.